# What is the right combination to use Paging and styling in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I may not be finding the best way to ask this, but I'm learning MVC by trying to build a small website. This is supposed to be a shopping website. Here I am on the part of displaying items on the page. I came through webgrid, but its displaying items in tabular form. Should I learn the tricks of tables like those in html? Because I have heard they can be modified to give any view?
Or can there be other alternatives to webgrid? I really like its Paging feature. I don't think I'm good enough right now to code for that. I have tried some googling and found jqgrid but that also seems to be good for tabular representation of data. I have been trying with this webgrid thing from last night and its really not coming together all good. What else can be the option? I mean something abstract enough to provide me good looks of a shopping website's product page, when I can provide a List of products(the model) from controller to the view? Then what?
Update: Basically I wanna know what part am I missing? Modifying Table to create good views? using webgrid properly? Or am I using the webgrid wrongly? something else should be used in this scene?

Comment: Have you tried Telerik/Kendo controls?

Comment: Ok m trying on them. Downloading now. Thnq.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this simple of example of how to use Twitter Bootsrap to style a WebGrid: [WebMatrix WebGrid – Re-Working the Pager](http://www.mdobie.co.uk/2012/12/02/webmatrix-webgrid-re-working-the-pager/).

You can also check out the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) site for examples of other ways this can be used to transform tabular data.

Comment: Thnx but the real problem was whether to keep modifying the table looks till it reaches required look, or create a view of our own using custom Pagination. I finally went with second option. I firstly thought it must be TOO difficult to implement custom Pagination, but wasn't so. Again thanks btw :-)

Comment: Cool. Did you just create your own pagination then?

Comment: I'm  not sure if its implemented in the best ways on server side, but on client side, I think I did it. I passed page number back to controller(default 0), then skip NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_ON_PAGE * 20 items from database, and take next NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_ON_PAGE as result.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks... I created a pull request to the Re-Working the Pager plugin to make it compatible with Bootstrap3's pagination: https://github.com/mdobie/WebGridPagerReplacement/pull/2